# Convert ISO8601 date into string format yyyy-MM-dd with angular

Tags: angular, date, angular-material

I’m working on an app that has date fields with a material datepicker.
This datepicker returns dates objects in ISO 8601 format like this for example: 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z

I want to retrieve the string format yyyy-MM-dd  when the user has selected the date in the datepicker. I must perform checks on the dates entered selected by the user. At first, I created a custom validator, but I encountered difficulties regarding the dependancy injection, so I created a service to do this.

I can do this in 2 ways in my service, but I’m a little lost and I don’t know what the best solution is.

1°/First solution: using DatePipe

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

convert() {
  this.datePipe.transform(this.form.get('myDate').value, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
}
```

2°/Second solution: using formatDate(date) function

```
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}

  convert(this.form.get('myDate').value) {
    return formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', this.locale);
  }
```

What solutions would you prefer, is there one more suitable solution than another?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either solution is acceptable. Pipes are injectable so you can utilize the `transform` method programmatically as you are doing above so there is no issue in doing it that way.

As for `formatDate` that is actually the underlying implementation that the `DatePipe` uses, so using either is using the same exact logic.

So this comes down to preference. Personally I use `formatDate` so I don't need to inject the `DatePipe`, but that is purely a matter of preference. Not all pipes expose their underlying implementation for use so for some pipes you will need to use the pipe transform method.